# Modify Connection String Visual Studio 2015 with SQL Server 2000 using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2000

My connection string is:

```
<add name="VBX" 
     connectionString="data source=(local);
                       initial catalog=Hospital_System;
                       user id=sa; Password=''" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

It's working properly on without networking. But I want to use my application on network. When I am modify Data Source name from `(local)` to `Server` then I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=14633; handshake=13466;

Comment: Empty passwords for `sa`? Are you sure?

Comment: yes user is sa and password is empty..

Comment: You must use fully qualified name of your instance in form `<MACHINE>\<INSTANCE_NAME>`

Comment: i am using SQL 2000 Enterprise.
can you Guiding me. what is my `INSTANCE_NAME` ?? PLESE

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/EvXiMsl) is screenshot

Comment: @JohnyL Is it okay  ??  `data source=\\server\MSSQLSERVER`

Comment: Nope. `Data Source=server\MSSQLSERVER`

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: i am using  `Data Source=Server\MSSQLSERVER` and got this error
Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL

Comment: 1. The default instance name for SQL Server is blank (apart from Express, when it is 'sqlexpress'). 2. You can avoid a lot of problems with formatting etc by using a connectionstringbuilder.

Comment: @peterG can you help me...
i am not getting how can i do this.....

Comment: any Body can ??